# Is there a way to display dinamic widget of categories leaving one of them out in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I want to have a widget inside by sidebar that show all the **categories** (**except one**) of my wordpress site.

Want to made it **dinamical** so whenever I made a new category, by deafult appear inside my widget.

I already tried to insert the wordpress' default widget of the categories but doing this it show me all the categories and I **don't have any possibilities to hide one** as I want.

There is any fix for this problem?

I'm using **Basel theme 5.0.0** and **version 5.4.2 of wordpress**. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The default widget has some hook :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/widget_categories_args

As the sample do, you can exclude programmatically any categories.

---

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192051/hide-specific-categories-from-category-widget